# Cannot implement interface member because it does not have the matching return type

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface

I'm not sure what the problem is here but i get the following compiler error:

**ERROR:**

> Error 3   'DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork' does not
>   implement interface member 'Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork.IUow.DBC'.
>   'DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork.DBC' cannot implement
>   'Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork.IUow.DBC' because it does not have the
>   matching return type of
>   'Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork.IDBContext'.    ..\DataAccess.NHibernate\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWork.cs   12  11  DataAccess.NHibernate

Bellow is my code

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
namespace DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork
{
    class UnitOfWork : IUow, IDisposable
    {
        public DBContext DBC { get; set; }
        public ISession Session;
        public ITransaction Transaction;

        public void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        { 
            //some code
        }
        public void Commit()
        {
            //some code
        }
        public void Rollback()
        {
            //some code
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //some code
        }
        public UnitOfWork(ISession session)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

**DBContext.cs**

```
namespace DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork
{
    public class DBContext
    {
        public IUow UnitOfWork { get; set; }
        public IUserRepository UserRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return new NHibernateUsersRepository(this.UnitOfWork);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IUow.cs**

```
namespace Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork
{
    public interface IUow : IDisposable
    {
        IDBContext DBC { get; set; }

        void Commit();
        void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
        void Dispose();
        void Rollback();
    }
}
```

**IDBContext.cs**

```
namespace Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork
{
    public interface IDBContext
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UnitOfWork : IUow, IDisposable
{
    public DBContext DBC { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

needs to be

```
class UnitOfWork : IUow, IDisposable
{
    public IDBContext DBC { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

so that it matches your interface:

```
public interface IUow : IDisposable
{
    IDBContext DBC { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The error message explains this

`Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork.IUow.DBC' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Domain.Repository.UnitOfWork.IDBContext'`

Answer (score 1):

You state in your contract (interface) that you will return:

```
IDBContext DBC { get; set; }
```

But you implement it as:

```
public DBContext DBC { get; set; }
```

which doesn't implement IDBContext:

```
public class DBContext
```

Change it to:

```
public class DBContext : IDBContext
```

and it should work.